# MySQL - UNION 2 Tables then ORDER BY

Tags: mysql, database, union, sql-insert, join

I am combining two queries and I am using UNION to combine these two result sets.

**First Query:**

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT bsb.ID AS order_item_id, bsb.NAME AS order_item_name, 'line_item' AS order_item_type, bsb.ORDER_ID AS order_id 
  FROM b_sale_basket bsb 
   WHERE bsb.ORDER_ID IN (810, 255)
UNION
```

**Second Query:**

```
SELECT bso.ID AS order_item_id, bsd.NAME AS order_item_name, 
'shipping' AS order_item_type, bso.ID AS order_id FROM b_sale_order bso 
 LEFT OUTER JOIN b_sale_delivery bsd ON bso.DELIVERY_ID = bsd.ID 
   WHERE bso.ID IN (255, 810)) order_union_result
```

The results of these two queries are good and looks like this:

[image]

I tried putting a ORDER BY clause at the end of the second query so that after all ordered_items there is a **SHIPMENT ROW below**

```
UNION
SELECT bso.ID AS order_item_id, bsd.NAME AS order_item_name, 'shipping' AS order_item_type, bso.ID AS order_id
FROM b_sale_order bso
LEFT OUTER JOIN b_sale_delivery bsd ON bso.DELIVERY_ID = bsd.ID
WHERE bso.ID IN (255, 810)) order_union_result ORDER by bso.ID
```

But it prompts me with an error of: **#1054 - Unknown column 'bso.ID' in 'order clause'**

The result should look like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZCfLk.png

Note: I want to sort the rows so that after all ordered items are, there is a shipping row below them

Kindly help me. Thank you for any help is appreciated

Comment: Try to use `order_union_result ORDER by order_item_id`

Comment: Hello Jens, Thanks for the quick reply. I tried your suggestion but it won't sort because they have different order_item_id like in the image

Comment: @Redsot: Have you tried to order by `order_id`?

Comment: Hello Jens.. I have solved the answer.. I used two fields to order by.. You should have posted you answer as a real answer like Samonth did so that I could make the green check mark.. Thanks again Jens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `order_id` instead of `bso.ID`. This should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ORDER by order_item_id
```

You should use aliases in ORDER BY clause

Comment: Hello Samoth, I also tried ORDER by order_item_id but it won't be sorted because the first columns has different id values....